# Java Mockito - Unable to throw IOException during DocumentBuilder.parse

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am trying to create a JUnit test to fire IOException during DocumentBuilder.parse(InputSource.class).

I not sure why my "doThrow" method is not firing IOException.

The source code is as below:
JUnit class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:META-INF/spring/test.xml" })
@Transactional
public class junitTestClass {

    @InjectMocks
    TargetClass target;

    @Rule
    public MockitoRule mockito = MockitoJUnit.rule();

    @Mock
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder;

    @Mock
    DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory;

    @Mock
    XPath xpath;

    @Test
    public void test01() throws InterruptedException, SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException{

        when(documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder()).thenReturn(documentBuilder);
        doThrow(new IOException()).when(documentBuilder).parse(any(InputSource.class));

        String xml = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><aaa><bbb>123</bbb></aaa>";
        String pattern = "//aaa/bbb";

        try {
            target.parseXML(xml, pattern);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Main Class:

```
private String parseXML(String xml, String pattern) {
        String itemValue ;

        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dFac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dFac.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
            XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            Node msgId = (Node) xPath.compile(pattern).evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODE);
            itemValue = msgId.getTextContent();
        } catch (XPathExpressionException | SAXException | ParserConfigurationException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return itemValue;
    }
```

Comment: because you are doing mocking wrong. You actually create a new instance in `DocumentBuilder db = dFac.newDocumentBuilder();` because you use `DocumentBuilderFactory dFac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();`

Comment: So you need to either mock that static factory method (if that is possible), or configure it to return your mocked builder (if that is possible) or inject the DocumentBuilderFactory into your code (so that you can pass along the mock you made).

Comment: Thnx michalk and Thilo.
Currently, I only can change JUnit class.
In this case, how do I mock that static factory method?

Comment: You will have to use PowerMock for this, unless you want to make your design more testable - using dependency injection for example.

Comment: Mockito doesn't support mocking static methods. If you want to continue using `static` you should move to another mocking framework, as PowerMock.
On the other hand if you can change the classes to allow dependency injection, via constructor, setter, .... you code will become more testable IMHO

Comment: Hi all, how do I proceed with PowerMock?
I tried this but it return error:

DocumentBuilderFactory mockDocumentBuilderFactory = PowerMockito.mock(DocumentBuilderFactory.class);
     PowerMockito.when(mockDocumentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder()).thenThrow(new ParserConfigurationException("Simulated ex"));

PowerMockito.mockStatic(DocumentBuilderFactory.class);
     PowerMockito.when(DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()).thenReturn(mockDocumentBuilderFactory);

It stated: when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.

Comment: Can you guys provide with some powermock example?

Comment: Taking a step back, why do you need to inject a mock XML engine? Why not just use the normal (real) one? You should be able to just assume that the XML engine works (it is not your code anyway), and you can test with all kinds of `String xml` and `String pattern` to see how you code deals with them? What test scenario is not covered by that?

Answer (score -2):

You should use:

```
doThrow(IOException.class)
```

Instead of instantiating it.

Comment: Look at his code closely. This is not a problem here.